# rails jquery select2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

What is the right way to add the `allowClear` option to the select2 widget in my view?

```
$ ->
  $("#practice_toolkeeper").select2().select2('val',$("#toolkeeper_value").val())
```

I have the following code in my view:

```
<%= f.select :toolkeeper, options_from_collection_for_select(@people, :id, :name), :prompt => "Select type question" %>
```

Which generates this HTML:

```
<select id="practice_toolkeeper" name="practice[toolkeeper]">
    <option value="">Select type question</option>
    <option value="21">sdifj</option> 
    <option value="20">maxam</option> 
    <option value="22">maxab</option> 
    <option value="19">maxa</option> 
    <option value="23">dafuq</option> 
    <option value="15">bla</option> 
    <option value="24">asdasdasd</option> 
    <option value="13">abl</option> 
    <option value="17">Testa</option> 
</select>
```

I've tried many variations, but none is working yet...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do a few things to get this to work:

1. Set the `allowClear` and `placeholder` options in an options object that you use when initializing the widget:

   ```
   $ ->
     $("#practice_toolkeeper")
         .select2({ 
             allowClear: true,
             placeholder: 'Select type question'
         })
         .select2('val',$("#toolkeeper_value").val())
   ```
2. It looks like the `allowClear` option only works when there's an empty `option` in the `select`. To generate an empty option you could use `{:include_blank => true}` when generating the select:

   ```
   <%= f.select :toolkeeper, options_from_collection_for_select(@people, :id, :name), {:include_blank => true} %>
   ```

   Basically you want your HTML to look like this:

   ```
   <select id="practice_toolkeeper" name="practice[toolkeeper]">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value="21">sdifj</option> 
       <!-- etc -->
   </select>
   ```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Z63d7/

Comment: @HappyHacking: Make sure you specify the `placeholder` option (see above)

Comment: Can you show the markup you're working with so I can reproduce it?

Comment: sorry i'm quite new to jquery and so on.. what do you meen with markup :S

Comment: No problem, just the HTML rails is generating for you. You can view it by hitting "View source" on the webpage you're developing. I'll only need to see the HTML you're applying the select2 widget to.

Comment: @HappyHacking: Ok, I'll add it to your question instead of my answer.

Comment: oooh damn sorry... it's too late for me.. I've been up for 32 hours now :S

Comment: do you need other info, too? I've trying this since 2 hours and it seams wierd...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27257/discussion-between-andrew-whitaker-and-happyhacking)

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Can you tell how to [initialize the selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634267/how-to-initialize-the-selection-for-rails-select2-in-backboneforms-schemata) for the dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

*For My Developer Fellas Landed here*

Suppose You are using [Formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) Normally with Active Admin You can pass during declaration

```
f.input :your_select_2_field, { as: :select2, collection: ['a', 'b'], include_blank: 'Select Nothing'}
```

**Concentrate On Curly Braces {}**

-Happy Coding :)