# How to initialize the selection for rails-select2 in BackboneForms schema?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, marionette, jquery-select2, backbone-forms, select2-rails

The project uses [marionette-rails](https://github.com/rahilsondhi/marionette-rails), [backbone-on-rails](https://github.com/meleyal/backbone-on-rails), [select2-rails](https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails) and this [port to BackboneForms](https://gist.github.com/Integral/5156170) to provide a multiselect form field. The select options are available to the user. They are retrieved from the collection containing the total list of options:

```
MyApp.module("Products", function(Products, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {

  Products.CustomFormView = Products.CustomView.extend({

    initialize: function(options) {
      this.model.set("type", "Product");
      Products.EntryView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    schemata: function() {
      var products = this.collection.byType("Product");
      var productTypes = products.map(function(product){
        return {
          val: product.id,
          label: product.get("name")
        };
      });

      return {
        productBasics: {
          name: {
            type: "Text",
            title: "Name",
            editorAttrs: {
              maxLength: 60,
            }
          },
          type: {
            type: 'Select2',
            title: "Product type",
            options: {
              values: productTypes,
              value: [3, 5],
              initSelection: function (element, callback) {
                var data = [];
                $(element.val().split(",")).each(function () {
                  data.push({id: this, text: this});
                });
                callback(data);
              }
            },
            editorAttrs: {
              'multiple': 'multiple'
            }
          }
        }
      };
    }

  });
});
```

Do I initialize the `value` correctly in `options.value`? How comes `initSelection` is never called? I copied the function from the documentation - it might be incomplete for my case. None of the products with the IDs `3` and `5` is displayed as the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initSelection` is only used when data is loaded asynchronously. My understanding is that there is no way of specifying the selection upon initialization if you are using an array as the data source for a Select2 control.

The best way of initializing the selection is by using `setValue` after the form is created. Here is a simplified example based on the code in your example.

```
var ProductForm = Backbone.Form.extend({
  schema: {
    type: {
      type: 'Select2',
      title: "Product type",
      options: {
        values: productTypes,
      },
      editorAttrs: {
        'multiple': 'multiple'
      }
    }
  });

var form = new ProductForm({
  model: new Product()
}).render();

form.setValue("type", [3, 5]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `value` function (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation) in `setValue`. I personally recomend you to use this backbonme-forms plugin: https://gist.github.com/powmedia/5161061
There is a thread about custom editors: https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms/issues/144

Comment: Thanks for the documentation hint. I understand that I have to set the selection as `options: { value: [3, 5] }`. Where should I provide `initSelection`? Do I need to extend the [editor for backbone-forms](https://gist.github.com/Integral/5156170)? Please add some code snippets.

Comment: I can see how you load the `config` from the `schema` in [gist:5161061](https://gist.github.com/powmedia/5161061). But can you specify how you define `options.value` resp. `config.value` and `initSelection` if needed? Please add some code.

Comment: I guess `initSelection` belongs into the options as the documentation states: *"Notice that in order to use this method you must define the initSelection function in the options ..."*

Comment: Hi! I think you don't need `initSelection` until you begin to use some remote features e.g. ajax loading. You just need to provide options in `config` object just like with HTML page.
```"nodeType": {
  "title": "Node type",
  "type": "Select2",
  "config": {
    "tags": ["tag 1","tag 2","tag 3","tag 4","tag 5","tag 6","tag 7"],
    "width": "300"
  }
}```
or

```state: { title: 'State', type: 'Select2', config: {width: '300', data: [{id:'1',text:'State 1'},{id:'2',text:'State 2'}]}}```

And yeah: use https://gist.github.com/powmedia/5161061 until you need something like object as a result.

Comment: But the data I want to display is an object of type *"Product"* and I need to display its `name` as the current selection. Please refer to the code snippet I provided in your answer. Otherwise its hard to match.

Comment: Okay. Try to use this: https://gist.github.com/Integral/5998949
Pass into options `multiple: true` and `data` object with `id` and `value`. I think that you must rename `schemata` to `schema`. If you have some json API I can post solution for ajax select2.

Comment: Oh, and you'll need to use `Select2Rel` type.